# Model is empty after update but data is saved to the database and shown on reload

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm updating a model using the following controller:

**payment_controller.js**

```
App.PaymentNewController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    needs: ['student'],
    isNew: true,

    actions: {
        createPayment: function() {
            var date = new Date(this.get('date'));
            if (!date) { return false; }

            var amount = this.get('amount');
            if (!amount) { return false; }

            var studentId = this.get('controllers.student.id');

            if (this.isNew)
            {
                var payment = this.store.createRecord('payment', {
                    date: date,
                    amount: amount,
                });
            }
            else
            {
                var payment = this.get('model');
                payment.set('date', date);
                payment.set('amount', amount);
            }

            var self = this;

            var onSuccess = function(payment) {
                self.set('date', '');
                self.set('amount', '');

                self.transitionToRoute('student', studentId);
            };

            var onFail = function(payment) {
            };

            if (this.isNew)
            {
                this.store.find('student', studentId).then(function(student){
                    payment.set('student', student);

                    payment.save().then(onSuccess, onFail);
                });
            }
            else
            {
                payment.save().then(onSuccess, onFail);
            }
        },
    }
});
```

The data returned from the server is the following, and it looks in the correct format expected by ember:

> {"payment":{"amount":1111,"date":"2014-09-09T00:00:00.000Z","student":"54024bb9cd52254e181325af","_id":"54024bdacd52254e181325b0"}}

The issue is that after saving the data is correctly saved to the database, but in the store is empty (UPDATE: except the id). As soon as I reload the page the data is shown correctly and is the updated version of the model. This made me think to the fact that the error could lie in the response of the PUT request, but it looks fine to me.

I've been trying many different things with no success. I can provide additional code or info if needed.

**UPDATE 1**

Here are the involved routes:

```
App.StudentsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return this.store.find('student');
    }
});

App.StudentRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(params) {
        return this.store.find('student', params.student_id);
    }
});

App.StudentEditRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    setupController: function(controller, model) {
        this.controllerFor('student.new').setProperties({isNew:false, content:model});
    },

    renderTemplate: function() {
        this.render('student/new');         
    }
});

App.PaymentNewRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return this.store.createRecord('payment');
    } 
});

App.PaymentEditRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    setupController: function(controller, model) {
        this.controllerFor('payment.new').setProperties({isNew:false, content:model});
    },

    renderTemplate: function() {
        this.render('payment/new');         
    }
});
```

**UPDATE 2**

Here are the serializer and the adapter:

```
App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
    host: 'http://localhost:3000',
});

App.ApplicationSerializer = DS.RESTSerializer.extend(DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin, {
    primaryKey: '_id',
    serializeId: function(id) {
        return id.toString();
    },
    attrs: {
        payments: {embedded: 'always'},
        lessons: {embedded: 'always'}
    }
});
```

**UPDATE 3**

Here are the models:

```
App.Student  = DS.Model.extend({
    firstName: DS.attr('string'),
    lastName: DS.attr('string'),
    email: DS.attr('string'),
    nationality: DS.attr('string'),
    dateOfBirth: DS.attr('date'),

    payments: DS.hasMany('payment'),
    lessons: DS.hasMany('lesson'),
});

App.Payment  = DS.Model.extend({
    student: DS.belongsTo('student'),

    date: DS.attr('date'),
    amount: DS.attr('number'),
});
```

**UPDATE 4**

While inspecting the store using the Ember Inspector in Chrome I've noticed that after the update is completed, the only property that contains data in the payment object (in the store) is the id. Both date and amount are empty.
[image: Empty data in model after update]

Comment: Could you provide listView route?

Comment: Can we see the serializer/adapter being used?

Comment: Just a guess, but maybe Ember Data doesn't like `_id` as your property name instead of `id`?

Comment: @JoshPadnick I'm using the serializer to specify that the _id is the primaryKey and it's working properly for creating a model, so I cannot see any reason why it shouldn't work for updating it

Comment: Add the method `extractSingle: function(store, type, payload, id, requestType) { return this._super.apply(this,arguments);}` to your `Serializer` and stop it there in the debugger and examine the payload.

Comment: @SteveH. I've added your code to the `Serializer` and inspected the payload: it contains all the correct fields with the correct data in a `payment` object

Comment: Arg...  any chance you can reduce this down to a fiddle?

Comment: Can you include your `DS.Model` definition?  Also, in our app, we also use the `EmbeddedRecordsMixin`, but we define a serializer on a per-model basis, not at the application level. I'm wondering if Ember is expecting something to embedded and since it's missing in your response (potentially), decides it can't save this to the local store.

Comment: @JoshPadnick Model definitions added. Regarding the `EmbeddedRecordsMixin` defined at the application level, I suppose what you say makes sense, however the creation of a new model is working perfectly and only the update is affected by this issue

Comment: @kristjanreinhold Routes added

Comment: @Kingpin2k Serializer and adapter added